# How to identify what ERP system in use by the client just looking the table names in the SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, erp

I was wondering is there an easy way to identify ERP system name by just looking the provided SSMS table names.Ex. table bdbd.init

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless they are labeled before the tables is sent into you db.